# how to split this line using regular expression in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Input

`-n. 1 geographical map or plan, esp. for navigation. 2 sheet of information in the form of a table, graph, or diagram. 3 (usu. in pl.) colloq. listing of the currently best-selling pop records. -v. make a chart of, map. [Latin charta: related to *card1]`

I need to split this like this

`-n.`
`1 geographical map or plan, esp. for navigation.`
`2 sheet of information in the form of a table, graph, or diagram.`
`3 (usu. in pl.) colloq. listing of the currently best-selling pop records.`
`-v.`
`make a chart of, map. [Latin charta: related to *card1]`

My Expression is here 
`((—\w\.)|(\d\s))(([^\d—])*)`

But this fails on `card1]`

How to solve this?

How to negate `digit followed with space`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize lookahead:

```
((-\w\.)|(\d\s))(([^\d-]|(\d(?!\s))|(-(?!\w\.)))*)
```

You want any number of non-digits or non-dashes (`[^\d-]`), but you also want to allow digits that aren't followed by spaces `(\d(?!\s))` and hyphens that aren't followed by characters and periods `(-(?!\w\.))`.

Answer (score -1):

You should do [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) to your input string.

Comment: What has this to do with the question? `Regex.Escape` makes only sense if the input should be used as part of a regular expression and the whole user input has to matched literally e.g. a `]` should be matched literally.